# How can I improve the cosine similarity of two documents(sentences) in doc2vec model?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am building a NLP chat application in Python using `gensim` library through `doc2vec` model. I have hard coded documents and given a set of training examples, I am testing the model by throwing a user question and then finding most similar documents as a first step. In this case my test question is an exact copy of a document from training example.

```
import gensim
from gensim import models
sentence = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'sampling',u'what',u'is',u'tell',u'me',u'about'],tags=["SENT_0"])
sentence1 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'eligibility',u'what',u'is',u'my',u'limit',u'how',u'much',u'can',u'I',u'claim'],tags=["SENT_1"])
sentence2 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'eligibility',u'I',u'am',u'retiring',u'how',u'much',u'can',u'claim',u'have', u'resigned'],tags=["SENT_2"])
sentence3 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'what',u'is',u'my',u'eligibility',u'post',u'my',u'promotion'],tags=["SENT_3"])
sentence4 = models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words=[u'what',u'is', u'my',u'eligibility' u'post',u'my',u'promotion'], tags=["SENT_4"])
sentences = [sentence, sentence1, sentence2, sentence3, sentence4]
class LabeledLineSentence(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
    def __iter__(self):
        for uid, line in enumerate(open(filename)):
            yield LabeledSentence(words=line.split(), labels=['SENT_%s' % uid])
model = models.Doc2Vec(alpha=0.03, min_alpha=.025, min_count=2)
model.build_vocab(sentences)
for epoch in range(30):
    model.train(sentences, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs = model.iter)
    model.alpha -= 0.002  # decrease the learning rate`
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha  # fix the learning rate, no decay
model.save("my_model.doc2vec")
model_loaded = models.Doc2Vec.load('my_model.doc2vec')
print (model_loaded.docvecs.most_similar(["SENT_4"]))
```

Result:

```
[('SENT_1', 0.043695494532585144), ('SENT_2', 0.0017897281795740128), ('SENT_0', -0.018954679369926453), ('SENT_3', -0.08253869414329529)]
```

Similarity of `SENT_4` and `SENT_3` is only `-0.08253869414329529` when it should be 1 since they are exactly same. How should I improve this accuracy? Is there a specific way of training documents and I am missing something out?

Comment: First of all SENT_4 and SENT_3 are not exactly same. look at the word "promotion"

Comment: After correction:[('SENT_1', 0.043695494532585144), ('SENT_2', 0.0017897281795740128), ('SENT_0', -0.018954679369926453), ('SENT_3', -0.08253869414329529)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word2Vec/Doc2Vec don't work well on toy-sized examples (such as few texts, short texts, and few total words). Many of the desirable properties are only reliably achieved with training sets of millions of words, or tens-of-thousands of documents.

In particular, with only 5 examples, and only a dozen or two words, but 100-dimensions of modeling vectors, the training isn't forced to do the main thing which makes word-vectors/doc-vectors useful: compress representations into dense embeddings, where similar items *need* to be incrementally nudged near each other in vector space, because there's no way to retain all the original variation in a sort-of-giant-lookup-table.  With more dimensions than corpus variation, your identical-tokens `SENT_3` and `SENT_4` can adopt wildly different doc-vectors, and the model is still large enough to do great on its training task (essentially, 'overfit'), without the desired end-state of similar-texts having similar-vectors being forced.

You can sometimes squeeze a little more meaning out of small datasets with more training iterations, and a much-smaller model (in terms of vector `size`), but really: these vectors need large, varied datasets to become meaningful.

That's the main issue. Some other inefficiencies or errors in your example code:

- Your code doesn't use the class `LabeledLineSentence`, so there's no need to include it here – it's irrelevant boilerplate. (Also, `TaggedDocument` is the preferred name for the `words`+`tags` document class in recent gensim versions, rather than `LabeledSentence`.)
- Your custom-management of `alpha` and `min_alpha` is unlikely to do anything useful. These are best left at their defaults unless you already have something working, understand the algorithm well, and then want to try subtle optimizations.
- `train()` will do its own iterations, so you don't need to call it many times in an outer loop. (This code as written does in its first loop 5 `model.iter` iterations at `alpha` values gradually descending from 0.03 to 0.025, then 5 iterations at a fixed alpha of 0.028, then 5 more at 0.026, then 27 more sets of 5 iterations at decreasing alpha, ending on the 30th loop at a fixed alpha of -0.028. That's a nonsense ending value – the learning-rate should never be negative – at the end of a nonsense progression. Even with a big dataset, these 150 iterations, about half happening at negative `alpha` values, would likely yield weird results.)